# MYSQL - select max score of each player for each day

Tags: mysql, group-by, max

assuming we have a table like below

```
  name   |  userid  |  score  |      datestamp      |
-----------------------------------------------------
  john   |    1     |   44    |  2011-06-10 14:25:55 
  mary   |    2     |   59    |  2011-06-10 09:25:51 
  john   |    1     |   38    |  2011-06-10 21:25:15 
  elvis  |    3     |   19    |  2011-06-10 07:25:18
  ...
  marco  |    4     |   100   |  2011-03-10 07:25:18
```

i want to display the high-score of each user in each single day.

so for eaxmple if the player john have played ten rounds in the 2001-06-10 i want to display the the best score of that day, and so on for the others players.

thank you very much for the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT name, MAX(score) AS hiscore, DATE(datestamp) AS sdate
FROM scores
GROUP BY userid, sdate
ORDER BY sdate DESC
```

But also notice that your table is not even in the [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) because it lacks an unique key. Also after fixing that, name of players will be repeated, and it will have to be extracted in a separate table for the second normal form.

A normalised design will have two tables:

```
player(userid, name)
scores(scoreid, userid, score, datestamp)
```

Comment: I think the design of the tables goes beyond the answer Julie was looking for. However, I absolutely agree with you on that.

Comment: thank's to everyone, my initial query was exactly like this one or the other by Mostly Mostacho, just now i have realized that my problem is elsewhere! ;-)

Comment: How do you know that there is no unique key? `(userid,datestamp)` looks like a good canidate.

Comment: actually from the fact that user_id 1 shows 2 times, you would know it's not unique

Comment: @renevdkooi, ypercube was thinking that there might be a unique key on the couple (userid, datestamp), not on only user_id

Answer (score 2):

Not tested, but what about?

```
select userid, max(score), date(datestamp) from table
group by userid, date(datestamp)
```